# Angular File Saver in spring rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, filesaver.js

I'm trying to implement  FileSaver.js  like this example  https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver to download generated file by spring boot application ,I have rest service that return the file as byte array data.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateReport/{reportId}/{parameters}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public  byte[] generateReport(@PathVariable("reportId") String reportId,
                                @PathVariable("parameters") String parameters
                                ) {

        byte[] bFile;
        //some code

        return bFile;
     }
```

Angular service

```
'generateReport': {
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer' ,
            url: 'adap_report/api/generateReport/:reportId/:parameters',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                }
                return data;
                }
        },
```

Angularjs controller

```
 vm.generateReport = function() {
        Report.generateReport({reportId:entity.id,parameters:angular.toJson(vm.parameterList)}, function(result) {
        var data = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');
        });
    };
```

File saver works and file downloaded but The content is wrong ,I just get file with this content

```
[object Object]
```

Can anyone please help me to save generated file with angular FileSaver.js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by http

```
 $http.get('/adap_report/api/generateReport/'+entity.id+'/'+angular.toJson(vm.parameterList), {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
          .success(function (data) {
              console.log(data)

              if(entity.reportoutputtypecode=="PDF"){
                  var blobData = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
                  window.open(fileURL);               
              }else{
                var blobData = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/'+entity.reportoutputtypecode});
                FileSaver.saveAs(blobData, 'jasper-file.'+entity.reportoutputtypecode);
             }
          });
```